# Is there tool convert DRL file to XLS file

Tags: drools

At my workplace we are moving from .drl files to .xls files so that the business analysts can better understand the rules and can communicate with the business faster. Our rule base is pretty complicated and I was wondering if there was a tool which could take drl files as input and provide xls as output.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it works, but worth giving a try,

Configure 'jboss drools guvnor', upload your drl file, there are options to download PKG files and some thing else. I believe one of the link enable you to download csv/xls . I am not sure though, used drools quite long back

Comment: Unfortunately that won't perform any kind of conversion from .drl to .xls or the other way around. Downloading .xls is for rules which are already in .xls form.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no such tool, as DRL is a free-format style of rule whereas spreadsheets and web decision tables are just templates for very rigidly-structured rules.

In general, if your rule base is complex, then spreadsheets are unlikely to support it very well. They work best for large numbers of simple (almost identical) rules.

If your rules are simple and almost identical, then potentially you could knock up a script to parse the DRL and generate spreadsheets. But that's only worth doing if you have large numbers of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try This to convert to XML first, then from there to XLSX

```
public class DroolsConversionHelper {

 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
  System.out.println(convertDrlFileToXml("/sample.drl"));
  System.out.println(convertXmlToDrlFile("/sample.xml"));
 }
 
 private static String convertDrlFileToXml(String drlFileName) throws Exception {
  Reader source = new InputStreamReader(
   DroolsConversionHelper.class.getResourceAsStream(drlFileName));
  DrlParser drlParser = new DrlParser();
  PackageDescr pkgDesc = drlParser.parse(source);
  XmlDumper xmlDumper = new XmlDumper();
  String xml = xmlDumper.dump(pkgDesc);
  return xml;
 }
 
 private static String convertXmlToDrlFile(String xmlFileName) throws Exception {
  Reader source = new InputStreamReader(
    DroolsConversionHelper.class.getResourceAsStream(xmlFileName));
  XmlPackageReader xmlPackageReader = new XmlPackageReader();
  PackageDescr pkgDesc = xmlPackageReader.read(source);
  DrlDumper drlDumper = new DrlDumper();
  String drl = drlDumper.dump(pkgDesc);
  return drl;
 }
}
```